# My Atheros Ethernet network drive is not working with Xen Redhat client

Tags: ethernet, xen

I have TOSHIBA Satellite laptop Intel (R) Core (TM) i5-4200m CPU
I have installed Red Hat Enterprise Linux server 5 operating system into a Xen VM.
After I used these commands:

```
ifconfig eth0
/sbin/ifconfig
```

I get these outputs:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig eth0 
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

[root@localhost ~]# /sbin/ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:02:DA:F5  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

So my Atheros Ethernet network drive is not supported in RHEL-5.

I have a second operating system Ubuntu 13.10 release which is supported my Atheros Ethernet network,
After I used this command:lspci | grep –I net
I get this output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

So can I install Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10) manually in Red Hat Enterprise Linux server 5? If it is possible how I can do it? And how I can download my driver for Red Hat Enterprise Linux server 5?

Comment: I do not think this is a driver problem.  To confirm, add the output from `lspci` and `ls /sys/bus/pci/devices`.

Comment: Update to 5.10 and re-check.

Answer (score 2):

The Atheros drivers can be installed seperately. They're discussed here on the Linux Wireless project page on this page titled: [Atheros Linux wireless drivers](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/Atheros#Atheros_Linux_wireless_drivers).

Based on your model number, AR9565, you'll likely want the [ath9k module/driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k). Specifically your card is listed here for that driver:

```
AR9004:

AR9485 1x1 SB 11n PCIe
AR9462 2x2 DB 11n PCIe
AR9565 1x1 SB 11n PCIe
AR9580 3x3 DB 11n PCIe
AR9550 3x3 DB 11n
```

I believe you can use these instructions as described here: [Re: Need a Dell Driver for Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/ AR9565 FoOr UBUNTU 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044) to download these drivers from the Linux kernel website. These drivers are made available as backports to the various versions of the kernel.

- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/

You're going to have to download and compile the driver manually. I wasn't able to find a RPM that provided these directly. You might want to take a look through [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) on the off chance that it's offered there and I just missed it.

#### General steps to manually build

To download, pick the appropriate package for your kernel version.

> $ wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.9-rc4/compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s.tar.gz

Then unpack, build, and install it:

```
$ cd Desktop/compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s
$ sudo -i
$ ./scripts/driver-select ath9k
$ make
$ make install
$ reboot
```

Comment: [root@localhost compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s]# ./scripts/driver-select ath9k
Processing new driver-select request...
Backing up makefile: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/wireless/ath/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/ssb/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/bcma/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/misc/eeprom/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk

Comment: [root@localhost compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s]# make
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /home/salsabil/Desktop/compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s/.config /home/salsabil/Desktop/compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s/config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.el5xen/build M=/home/salsabil/Desktop/compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.el5xen/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: It looks like you have a fairly old version of the kernel here: 2.6.18-274.el5xen. You'll need to get the appropriate version of the compat-drivers for this one.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` by default only shows the interfaces that are *up*.  To see all the *available* interfaces, try `ifconfig -a`, `ip link show`, or `ls /sys/class/net`.

Note that your NIC won't necessarily be named `eth0` just because it is under some other distros.  Technically, it could be named anything -- this is determined by the system configuration -- although there are various (nb: various, as in more than one) standards for such.

If you see interfaces listed with `ifconfig -a` that aren't listed with `ifconfig`, put them up with `ifconfig [whatever] up` or `ip link set [whatever] up` and check again.  You should be able to figure out which one is the ethernet card, especially if you already know the MAC address.  You can also get a clue by following the symlink in `/sys/class/net`.

The fact that you have a `virbr0` also implies this is a VM (and not a hardware install), which may be significant, you may want to clarify that in your question if this does not help.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:14640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:23879872 (22.7 MiB)  TX bytes:23879872 (22.7 MiB)

Comment: veth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: veth1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: veth2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: veth3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: vif0.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: vif0.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: vif0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: vif0.3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:3440 (3.3 KiB)

Comment: xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# cd /sys/class/net
[root@localhost net]# ls
lo  veth0  veth1  veth2  veth3  vif0.0  vif0.1  vif0.2  vif0.3  virbr0  xenbr0

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [veth0] up
[veth0]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [veth1] up
[veth1]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [veth2] up
[veth2]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [vif0.0] up
[vif0.0]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [vif0.1] up
[vif0.1]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [vif0.2] up
[vif0.2]: unknown interface: No such device
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig [vif0.3] up
[vif0.3]: unknown interface: No such device

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for the square brackets to be used literally.  Try `ifconfig veth0 up` etc.  You are obviously running as a xen client and I have edited your question accordingly as this is probably significant.  *If you are not using Xen or a VM, something is very wrong* -- perhaps you downloaded the wrong Redhat image.